# How To set Json data in RecylerView in Hetrogeneous form of data in android studio

Tags: android, json, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-volley

This json data to set like this RecyelView list in android studio

```
[
    {
        "date": "03-01-2018",
        "price": 60.86,
        "company": "Bharat Petroleum",
        "city": "Panaji",
        "type": "Diesel"
    },
    {
        "date": "03-01-2018",
        "price": 64.49,
        "company": "Bharat Petroleum",
        "city": "Panaji",
        "type": "Petrol"
    },
    {
        "date": "03-01-2018",
        "price": 60.81,
        "company": "Indian Oil",
        "city": "Panaji",
        "type": "Diesel"
    },
    {
        "date": "03-01-2018",
        "price": 64.46,
        "company": "Indian Oil",
        "city": "Panaji",
        "type": "Petrol"
    },
    {
        "date": "03-01-2018",
        "price": 60.61,
        "company": "Bharat Petroleum",
        "city": "Margao",
        "type": "Diesel"
    },
    {
        "date": "03-01-2018",
        "price": 64.25,
        "company": "Bharat Petroleum",
        "city": "Margao",
        "type": "Petrol"
    },
    {
        "date": "03-01-2018",
        "price": 60.64,
        "company": "Indian Oil",
        "city": "Margao",
        "type": "Diesel"
    },
    {
        "date": "03-01-2018",
        "price": 64.27,
        "company": "Indian Oil",
        "city": "Margao",
        "type": "Petrol"
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you share code what yu have done?

Comment: how to set this json data  to set like this image https://imgur.com/a/g9IFt

Answer (score 0):

Using Gson u can achive with few lines of code ...`

```
 JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("yourJsonArrayKeyNameHere");
                                Type listType = new TypeToken<List<YourModelClassForEachRowOfData>>() {
                                }.getType();
                                List<YourModelClassForEachRowOfData> dataList = (List<YourModelClassForEachRowOfData>) new Gson().fromJson(jsonArray.toString(),
                                        listType);
```

and finally send this List to your recyclerview adapter ..that's it